# Several tasks not accessable in build.gradle file in connection with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, task

i found a weird behaviour in Android Studio.

I want to access the `dexDebug` task in my module build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testprj.test"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dexDebug.doFirst {
    // do some stuff here
}
```

But i get the following error: `Error:(rowNumber, 0) Could not find property 'dexDebug' on project ':app'.`

That's weird because i can call this task over the Android Studio terminal via `gradle dexDebug`.

What is the reason for it?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? `gradlew dexDebug` is not the same as `dexDebug.doFirst`.

Comment: I need to do some processing before the dexDebug task runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create your own task:**

```
task myTask() {

}
```

**Make your task "process stuff" before `dexDebug`:**

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->

    if (taskGraph.hasTask(dexDebug)) { // <-- check if your task is ready
        dexDebug.dependsOn myTask // <-- make it depend on your task
    }
}
```

Comment: Tanks man. Actually it don't work with the taskGraph stuff. I found a way to do that with the following
`tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if(task.name.equals('dexDebug')) {
        task.dependsOn myTask
    }
}`